# Reaching characters from USB HID keyboard device on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, usb, hid

I have a USB HID Keyboard connected to Linux and I do see /dev/input/event0, which returns keyboard event codes as described in www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt. I would prefer to read characters as you would from stdin. I do see that the kernel keyboard.c is doing the conversion as indicated by the log messages by evbug:

evbug.c: Event. Dev: input0, Type: 4, Code: 28, Value: 1
...

This suggests that characters are being fed to a character device (tty) but I am unable to find the device file that corresponds to this input. I believe a file like /dev/input/input0 should be present but I don't find it. I do see /proc/bus/input/devices will the following:

```
I: Bus=003 Vendor=2222 Product=0016 Version-0111
N: Name="Macally USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-ohci.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/class/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 evbug
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 7 ff800000 7ff febeffdf f3cfffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

I even tried 'mdev -s' but no additional devices were created. I may be missing a udev rule that creates the device node. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) First use [lsusb] command to find out device ID and serial number

2) Create mapping file in [/etc/udev/rules.d/]